Optimizing selection of unique records based on 2 columns
I have a large dataset stored in a table with columns entity_id, time, and group_id. I'm trying to efficiently retrieve unique records based on entity_id and time.
CREATE TABLE test_table (
    entity_id int,
    time BIGINT,
    group_id INT
  
);

INSERT INTO test_table (entity_id, time, group_id) VALUES 
(1, 1709049203345, 10086), 
(2, 1708605859234, 435146), 
(2, 1708605859234, 435146), 
(4, 1707815681971, 10086),
(5, 1707291871198, 10086),
(5, 1707291871198, 10086);




entity_id
time
group_id




1
1709049203345
10086


2
1708605859234
435146


2
1708605859234
435146


4
1707815681971
10086


5
1707291871198
10086


5
1707291871198
10086



I've attempted using both a CTE with ROW_NUMBER() and the DISTINCT ON clause, but both approaches are taking too long to process.
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        entity_id, 
        time, 
        group_id, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY entity_id, time ORDER BY entity_id) AS row_num
    FROM 
        test_table
)
SELECT 
    entity_id, 
    time, 
    group_id
FROM 
    cte
WHERE 
    row_num = 1;

and
SELECT DISTINCT ON (time, entity_id) *
FROM test_table
ORDER BY time, entity_id;

Can anyone suggest a more efficient method for achieving this?
I don't have write access to this database, I can only make SELECT statment.
db fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cQ6eELDAzHbr1nGK3iHBjK/0

I don't have write access to this database, I can only make SELECT statement, unfortunately  you must if adding/removing indexes are required.  You need to add an index  entity_id,time if not present and include the execution plan.

Booth your queries require sort full table on(entitiy_id,time).Any other variations of query require this sorting.  You (must) have index on (entitiy_id,time). In this case should be SELECT DISTINCT ON ( entity_id,time)

Could you please share the results from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for your SQL statement and the DDL for all tables and indexes involved? (All in plain text)
